# Is there a good way to know if you should transplant sunchokes to spread them out a little bit?

Tags: transplanting, sunchoke

It seems like a lot of my sunchokes are right next to each other, and I have about 3 feet of room. should I pull some up to move them a few feet so they all have room to grow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They will sufficiently spread when they will be tall.  Let them grow as is, and remove some if they are too close to each other.

But I doubt it would be a good thing to transplant the ones you will be removing in the process. There is various sites where the explain [how to grow them](http://www.harvesttotable.com/2009/03/how_to_grow_sunchoke/).

[Here](http://www.motherearthnews.com/organic-gardening/vegetables/growing-jerusalem-artichokes-zmaz10onzraw.aspx) they say its more an issue to contain them than to spread them...

Comment: So this season, just throw soil on top to keep them burried, or replant/use as animal fodder the green ones to not risk eating them myself?

Comment: If the green ones stay burried until next year, they will become fibrous... might be better to feed them to the animals or your composting pile

Comment: The neighbor has chickens, so that's where they will go I guess.